# Display Contents of List in WebPart

Tags: feature, list

How to make a feature to display the contents of a list in WebPart?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Content Query Web Part and configure the same to display the target list items in whatever way you want using XSL.

Further you can export that CQWP .webpart file and edit the same to remove the hardcoded list GUID reference and put up the list name insted.

Package the same in a feature and deploy it. This web part will then be availabe as preconfgured web part to display your target list contents.

Answer (score 1):

At it's most fundamental, if you edit the page then click "Add Web Part" at the top of one of the zones, find a list to display.

If you open the options to edit the web part, you can customize the "View" used to display the items, so you can select which columns to show, and also add grouping, filtering and sorting.